# How to fix websploit problem?

Tags: bash, python

When I tried to open `websploit`, this error message show up:

```
peter@peter-Satellite-C855:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for peter: 
root@peter-Satellite-C855:/home/peter# websploit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/websploit", line 55, in <module>
    from modules import arp_poisoner
  File "/usr/share/websploit/modules/arp_poisoner.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
ImportError: No module named scapy.all
root@peter-Satellite-C855:/home/peter#
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Related (on Stack Overflow): [Python scapy import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273936/python-scapy-import-error)

Answer (score 2):

Install the package `python-scapy` by running the following command in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scapy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use
su
apt-get install python2
apt-get install pip2
pip2 install scapy
```